# How to download and install IBM Websphere Application Server 7.0 for Linux

Tags: websphere, websphere-7

I need an old version of IBM WAS for Linux, the 7.0, but I don't understand in which way I can download it.

I go to the page: 
https://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27012960

There are reported the following steps:

```
Downloading and assembling the product
1. Navigate your browser to the Find Downloads and Media Web page on the IBM Passport Advantage Online Web site.
2. Select the Find by part number search option under Download finder options.
3. Search for each downloadable image by part number.
4. Download all of the required parts.
5. Use a file extracting utility that supports large file extractions to unpack each of the parts into a single, temporary directory on your system.
6. Open the Quick Start Guide, which is located on the Quick Start CD. Follow step three through step nine of the Quick Start Guide to access the documentation to help with product installation.
```

The [Find Downloads and Media Web](http://www-112.ibm.com/software/howtobuy/passportadvantage/paocustomer/sdma/SDMA?PO=DOWNLOAD_FIND_BY_PART_NUMBER) link should redirect us to:

http://www-112.ibm.com/software/howtobuy/passportadvantage/paocustomer/sdma/SDMA?PO=DOWNLOAD_FIND_BY_PART_NUMBER

But when you click on that link, I'm redirected to the page:

https://www-112.ibm.com/software/howtobuy/passportadvantage/paocustomer/blueid/Entitlement?jadeAction=DISPLAY_SELF_NOMINATION

Why it needs a self-nomination? What does it mean?
And what's referred to the "Site number" that is asked on that page?

I'm stuck on that step, I've tried to search for a Developer version but only 8.5.5+ versions seems available.

What I have to do?

Comment: WebSphere v7 end of support was in April, 2018: https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/aimsupport/entry/End_of_Support_for_WebSphere_v7_v8_and_Java_6_in_WebSphere_v8_5_April_2018?lang=en. I'd recommend using either v855 or v9.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Unfortunately, I still need that version, even if I would like to upgrade but it doesn't' depend on me...  However, I don't understand why they removed apparently the possibility to download it: for example, if you need an old version of Java you can still download it on the archives....

Comment: Your IBM rep should be able to help you get what you need.